# Finding and replacing a part of string in visual studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I am trying to find and replace a part of a quoted string in visual studio using regular expression (From find and replace dialog)
I am using this:

```
\"*.sale.*\"
```

It is working but the whole string is being selected for example if the string is:
saleCustomer
the whole word is being replaced, I need to only select and replace **sale**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use lookahead and lookbehind to match quotes and things leading to the string that you wish to replace:

```
(?<="[^"]*)sale(?=[^"]*")
```

Now only `sale` part would be captured and replaced.

Comment: if I need to extend it.
string Command = "[cup_SalesHD_UpdateCounterStatus]"; for example finding the sale word only if the statement contains the word command, as inn the example above, how this can be approached?

Comment: @HassanShouman You can add `command` to the lookbehind, like this: `(?<=command[^"]*"[^"]*)sale(?=[^"]*")`

Comment: Thank you! Saved my day!